# Display a hidden element / Simulate click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

at the bottom of the site, I have a Google Maps plugin. Here you can see a black marker. If you click that marker, it shows you a box with text inside it.

I want the box to be shown without having to click the marker first.

I thought i could solve this by imitating a click after the website has loaded, but i can't find out how to address that specific marker to click.

Could anyone hint me to a solution? I couldn't solve this without breaking the whole Map :/..

Thanks a lot.

This problem concerns the following website: 
http://prusiklackierbetrieb.de/neu/black/indexnewimages.html

I have found the location where the infowindow is created. However, when i change the event from "click" to "load" or "domready" it does not fire. i think it is because the script is loaded after these events fire. How can I still open the window by default?

Code Snippet:

```
!function(a) {
"use strict";
var t = {
    cntClass: "map",
    mapClass: "map_model",
    locationsClass: "map_locations",
    marker: {
        basic: "images/gmap_marker.png",
        active: "images/gmap_marker_active.png"
    },
    styles: [],
    onInit: !1
}
  , o = {
    map: {
        x: -73.9924068,
        y: 40.646197,
        zoom: 14
    },
    locations: []
}
  , n = function(t, o) {
    var n = t.parent().find("." + o.locationsClass).find("li")
      , e = [];
    return n.length > 0 && n.each(function(t) {
        var n = a(this);
        n.data("x") && n.data("y") && (e[t] = {
            x: n.data("x"),
            y: n.data("y"),
            basic: n.data("basic") ? n.data("basic") : o.marker.basic,
            active: n.data("active") ? n.data("active") : o.marker.active
        },
        a.trim(n.html()) ? e[t].content = '<div class="iw-content">' + n.html() + "</div>" : e[t].content = !1)
    }),
    e
};
a.fn.googleMap = function(e) {
    e = a.extend(!0, {}, t, e),
    a(this).each(function() {
        var t = a(this)
          , s = a.extend(!0, {}, o, {
            map: {
                x: t.data("x"),
                y: t.data("y"),
                zoom: t.data("zoom")
            },
            locations: n(t, e)
        })
          , i = new google.maps.Map(this,{
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(s.map.y),parseFloat(s.map.x)),
            styles: e.styles,
            zoom: s.map.zoom,
            scrollwheel: !1
        });
        e.onInit && e.onInit.call(this, i);
        var c = new google.maps.InfoWindow
          , l = [];
        for (var r in s.locations)
            l[r] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(s.locations[r].y),parseFloat(s.locations[r].x)),
                map: i,
                icon: s.locations[r].basic,
                index: r
            }),
            s.locations[r].content && (google.maps.event.addListener(l[r], "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                for (var t in l)
                    l[t].setIcon(s.locations[t].basic);
                c.setContent(s.locations[this.index].content),
                c.open(i, this),
                a(".gm-style-iw").parent().parent().addClass("gm-wrapper"),
                this.setIcon(s.locations[this.index].active)
            }),
            google.maps.event.addListener(c, "closeclick", function() {
                for (var a in l)
                    l[a].setIcon(s.locations[a].basic)
            }));
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            i.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(s.map.y),parseFloat(s.map.x)))
        })
    })
}}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you crate the infowindow just call [open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

You can look an example here https://www.ibeernalia.com/#dorigen .

Comment: This seems to be very close to what i need. But i cannot find the location where the infowindow is created.. Do you have any idea where that is?

Comment: how do you create the map? if you're using a wordpress template or similar you will probably have a built in option in the menu or you will need to contact template creators to know where you need to execute the `infowindow.open` command

Comment: thanks a lot, i found the location where it is created. however, i can still not open it without breaking the script. I would be really grateful if you could spare a few minutes and check the initial post. I edited it and added the new information :)

Answer (score 0):

The map is loaded in an IFRAME so you cannot simulate click on an element in the IFRAME.
What you can do it to use the Google Maps API for that

More Info:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows